# How to update specific object's element in array of other objects in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to update an element of an object, that belongs to an array, inside a document. Specifically, "updating the status of a specific order of a specific user in the collection"

I have the username of the user to edit in the collection, the orderID of the order in the array to edit, and the newStatus....

Here is the Schema and the mongoose code...

```
USER: {
  _id: objectId(as425as4526dc)
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'a61a8726ahf604s',
  fname: 'first',
  lname: 'last',
  date: '2018-9-9',
  orders: [
    {
       _id: objectID(012eoisadn3)
       status: 0,
       name: 'name'
       description: 'hello'
    }
  ]
 }
```

**MONGOOSE**

```
  const username = req.body.username;
  const orderID = req.body.id;
  const newStatus = req.body.status;

  User.update(
    {
      username: username,
      'orders._id': orderID
    },
    {
      $set:{
        'orders.$.status': newStatus
      }
    },
    function(err,docs){
     ...
     //Do Stuff Here
     ...
    }
  );
```

**RETURNS**

```
{ n: 0,
  nModified: 0,
  opTime:
   { ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1539373723 },
     t: 1 },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001,
  ok: 1,
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1539373723 },
  '$clusterTime':
   { clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1539373723 },
     signature: { hash: [Object], keyId: [Object] } } }
```

Comment: Is there an error you are getting? Your mongoose update looks ok.

Comment: I edited to add it the return. It simply says none were modified, leading me to believe that the selector was wrong

Comment: Yes verify that you have those objects in the db and that `req.body.username` and `req.body.id` are what you expect.

Comment: Where does `req.body` come from? If this was from a `User.findOne()` or equivalent, then you're trying to update an order with an ID that matches the user's ID. Whether or not this is the case, I would recommend examining your `orderID` value as that is likely your failing point.